# Quickest iteration in Python on 40gb of data - 106 million rows

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a .csv file with 40gb of data (106 million rows) as the title says. I need to subset based on a condition - one of the columns in the data is a list of words that needs proper adjusting on the fly. I need to subset it based on check of those words against another list.

Is it quicker to iterate through the file e.g., bring in one row of a data at a time and save it off it passes the test or load it all in a Pandas DataFrame and conduct the check there?

My intuition tells me loading it row by row and saving it off is better, but I am unsure.

Lastly, why is one quicker than the other on this size of data?

Comment: you might want to check [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) for pandas like syntax on huge files. Additionally, you might want to check [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html)

Comment: treating it as a stream will be *much* faster (+ saves you memory :) if you want maximum performance: work on the bytes directly instead of first casting to string.

Comment: If you can do the task in a stream operation then you most probably (imho always) should do so.

Comment: Thank you all. I have never heard of dask, but this look quite nice and much easier to use compared to pyspark. It does save on memory, which is the main reason I wrote in a streaming format first. I will look into working on the bytes directly, I have not done that before, as I haven't had a necessity.